# Want to show a <tr> on hover using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<head>
<title>On hover testing</title>
<style>
.hover:hover{
color:#F00;

}
.result{
display:none;
height:100px;
width:50px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="hover">Hover over me
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="result">
<td>This text shows on hover only
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>this is second line
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to show the  only on-hover . Kindly guide me how can i display this using java script. I am in learning stage kindly guide me. Thanks

Comment: You're in a learning stage, you must've tried something right? Show us your code!

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of any of your code, here is the basic idea:

```
$('.hover').hover(function(){
    $('.result').show();
},function(){
    $('.result').hide();
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/bj09dfq4/1/

The jQuery [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function takes two parameters. A function to call when your mouse enters the element and another to call when you leave the element.

In this case those functions do nothing but http://api.jquery.com/show/[enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) the other `class="result"` element.

You need to include jQuery in your page, before any scripts that use it. e.g. in the `head`:

```
<head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

If your script is placed *before* the elements in the page, you will also need to wrap it in a DOM ready handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.hover').hover(function(){
            $('.result').show();
        },function(){
            $('.result').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Notes:**

- `$(function(){....});` is just a handy shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

For @Pete_Gore, it is always possibly to make things slicker:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/bj09dfq4/

```
    $(function(){
        $('.hover').hover(function(){
            $('.result').toggle();
        });
    });
```

`hover()` also allows for a single "in/out" method and [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) switches between `hide()` and `show()`.

Comment: Please explain how to add jQuery also

Comment: Oh those saucy aussies.

Comment: Yay now it's perfect ^^

Comment: @Pete_Gore: Code is *never* perfect, but it will do for a newbie :)

Comment: Well, I think that 5 lines of code can be perfect ^^

Comment: @Pete_Gore: Nah... there is probably a shorter alternative using 1 line, a toggle and a goat (added an example... sans goat) :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add a JavaScript hover event onto the `.hover` class, like so:

```
$('.hover').hover(
    function() {
        // onmouseover
        $('.result').show();
    }, function() {
        // onmouseexit
        $('.result').hide();
    }
);
```

See the jQuery Hover documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)